# How to add placeholder to forms.widgets.DateInput with attrs={'type': 'date',} in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I cannot add a placeholder to `DateInput` widget inside a form if I pass `'type': 'date'` to `attrs`. However, if I don't pass `'type': 'date'` to `attrs` the field behaves like a `TextInput`.

It looks super simple but I can't understand what's going wrong.

**forms.py**

```
class QueryClientsForm(forms.Form):
    initial_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Initial date...', 'type': 'date', }))
```

**query_clients.html**

```
<div class="container h-50">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="register_card" style="display: inline-block;">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{form.initial_date}}
                    <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" style="margin-left: 10;" value="SEARCH">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use some `javascript` aswell but it didn't work...

```
<script>

    var initial_date = document.getElementById('id_initial_date')

    initial_date.placeholder = 'Initial date...';
    
</script>
```

What I've to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work adjusting the `onfocus` parameter and changing the `type` to text.

```
class QueryClientsForm(forms.Form):
    initial_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Initial date...', 'type': 'text',
                   'onfocus': "(this.type='date')", }
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass `attrs={'placeholder': 'Initial date...', 'type': 'date', }` to a form field in gets rendered as `<input type='date' placeholder='Initial date...'>`
but input field of type *date* in html5 **does not** support *placeholder* attribute.  when you remove the type attribute it's rendered as `type='text'` which supports *placeholder*. if you want to show placeholder text you should look for jQuery library which has that support. Lastly if you want to show an initial date instead of default 'mm/dd/yyy' you can initialise like this

```
class QueryClientsForm(forms.Form):
    inital_date = forms.DateField(
        initial=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(
            attrs={'type': 'date'})
    )
```

**UPDATE:**
If you use jQuery you can get the result using a workaround. Send *id* attribute instead of *type* in your form.

```
attrs={
    'placeholder': 'Initial date...',
    'id': 'date_field'
}
```

and in your template change *type* with jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#date_field").focus(function () {
            $(this).prop('type', 'date');

        });

        $("#date_field").focusout(function () {
            $(this).prop('type', 'text');

        });

    });
</script>
```